# Change parent class on list element based on child link element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify li class "blackcat-21 wnode" adding "active", because there is a link with class selected inside:

```
<a id="cat-21" href="" class="selected">link</a>
```

the parent "li"  should change in "blockcat-21 wnode active" .

```
<li class="blockcat-21 wnode">
                <a id="cat-21" href="" class="selected">link</a>
                    <ul style="display: block;">
                            <li class="blockcat-33">
                                <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="blockcat-22">
                                <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
                            </li>
                                <li class="blockcat-34 last">
                                <a id="cat-34" href="" class="noselect" title=""></a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
```

Comment: can we see the Jquery or JS please

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: may be he wants to add append a class but...it is getting appended as a child :imo

Comment: yes, I have to to append a class to "blockcat-21 wnode", to become "blockcat-21 wnode active"

Comment: @RobertoC. Can JQuery be used?

Answer (score 0):

Not a too difficult job though:
When the selected anchor element is a descendant of `wnode`

### Vanilla

We use `document.querySelector` with the selector `a.selected`. That searches for a an anchor element with class `selected`. Then we use `closest` to find it. And use `classlist` to add the class. If the browser doesn't support closest we can use a polyfill.

> `document.querySelector` returns the first child found. If you want to update more nodes that use brk's solution.

```js
//using very modern browsers
if (Element.prototype.closest) {
  document.querySelector("a.selected").closest(".wnode").classList.add("active");
}
//else
else {

  //use the polyfill from MDN
  if (!Element.prototype.matches)
    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector;

  if (!Element.prototype.closest)
    Element.prototype.closest = function(s) {
      var el = this;
      if (!document.documentElement.contains(el)) return null;
      do {
        if (el.matches(s)) return el;
        el = el.parentElement;
      } while (el !== null);
      return null;
    };
    
    document.querySelector("a.selected").closest(".wnode").classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="blockcat-21 wnode">
  <a id="cat-21" href="" class="selected">link</a>
  <ul style="display: block;">
    <li class="blockcat-33">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-22">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-34 last">
      <a id="cat-34" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

### With jQuery:

We select the active link using `a.selected`. We can use jQuery's closest here to get up the DOM-tree to the `wnode` ancestor. Then just use `addClass` and viola.

```js
$("a.selected").closest(".wnode").addClass("active");
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="blockcat-21 wnode">
  <a id="cat-21" href="" class="selected">link</a>
  <ul style="display: block;">
    <li class="blockcat-33">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-22">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-34 last">
      <a id="cat-34" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Just a note, if the <a> inside the id="cat-33" for example, become "select", so in 2th level down, how to to assign in the same way the class in the same parent <li>, like before ? (for same parent, I intend the "blockcat-21 wnode") that contain all.

Comment: Aha, I was wondering when that question came. Jquery is actually pretty handy for that. Vanilla is more difficult. Look at my update in a couple of minutes.

Comment: the problem is that I have to modify only the class with "wnode", because I could have 2th or 3th level class with "selected" class link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` and `parentNode` method. Here `document.querySelectorAll('a.selected')` will select all anchor tag which have `selected` class & parentNode will select it's parent

```js
var getAllSelected = document.querySelectorAll('a.selected');

for (var x = 0; x < getAllSelected.length; x++) {
    getAllSelected[x].parentNode.classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<li class="blockcat-21 wnode">
  <a id="cat-21" href="" class="selected">link</a>
  <ul style="display: block;">
    <li class="blockcat-33">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-22">
      <a id="cat-33" href="" class="noselect" title="">link 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="blockcat-34 last">
      <a id="cat-34" href="" class="noselect" title=""></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```